# Is there a way to configure a view of builds that I started in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

We have 'try' build jobs that developers can initiate with parameterized variables to point to a particular branch for pulling the code and trial running the build in jenkins. Is there a way I can customize a custom personal view showing only the builds that I have started?

Answer (score 1):

> **The custom way**

I think there's a way to customize a personal view by coding / modifying your Jenkins installation, jan-molak worked on that feature [here](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/pull/128).

[image: job_filter_by_user]

You can check the commits and maybe implement something by your own, especially [this](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/pull/128/commits/23cfc840150f3e8fb7b574c8244b520b992e80f3) and [this](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/pull/128/commits/204a1e9eb15dd24a4ab53c3cc1d44192839e03f5).

> **The plugin**

Take a look on [View Job Filter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) If you configure it, there are options which [seems to acomplis](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/controlling-what-you-see-view-job-filters-jenkins-plugin)h what you want:

> Logged-in User Relevance Filter: This adds/removes jobs based on their
>   relevance to the logged in user. For example: matching jobs that were
>   started by the user, or where the user committed changes to the source
>   code of the job; matching jobs with a name that contains the user’s
>   name or login id.

[image: Filter by building]

[image: match by user]

Comment: Yes that's the one I've been trying to use  `Match jobs with builds 'started by' user` to no avail...

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean "finished jobs by certain user " or "jobs in progress started by some user" both things are available in the plugin.

Comment: I'll try it again, wasn't able to filter by current user. I got all the jobs not limited to user started ones,